# Is there a need to do apply_filter('widget_title', $instance['title']) or any other 'widget_xxx' filters?

Tags: plugin-development, widgets

I am reading the book Professional Wordpress, and have code like

```
$title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);
$name = apply_filters('widget_name', $instance['name']);
...
```

I wonder if there really are filters like `widget_xxx`? What do they do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, it makes them editable using the [Front-end Editor](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/front-end-editor/) plugin.

All the cool widgets are doing it:

http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/wp-includes/default-widgets.php